How to find value vertically and horizontally, using formula in Sheets?
There has to be a couple of matches in a column and in the rows, so that the column header can be obtained, but I cannot do HLOOKUP and VLOOKUP at the same time.
I could do it via script, but if this requires maintenance, that would be harder to keep.
Here is the criteria set:

This is what the Pontuação column should show as the result:

Here is the link to the file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing

Here's a possible solution:
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAP(O3:O7;LAMBDA(a;TEXTJOIN(;;IF(B3:F=a;B2:F2;)))))

